# Swift unabel to find "" in scope

Tags: swift, xcode, scope, func, guard

So I'm trying to create an app with a login and register screen and I've created a guard function to create and add a new account in which i could log in later.

Thi is the implementation

```
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth
import Foundation

class RegisterViewViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var name = ""
    @Published var email = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    
    init(){}
    
    func register(){
        guard validate() else{
            return
        }
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] result, error in
            guard let userId = result?.user.uid else{
                return
            }
            self?.insertUserRecord(id: userId)
        }
    }
    
    private func insertUserRecord(id: String){
        let newUser =  User(id: id,
                            name: name,
                            email: email,
                            joined: Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("users")
            .document(id)
            .setData(newUser.asDictionary())
    }
    
    private func valdiate() -> Bool{
        guard !name.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty,
              !email.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty,
              !password.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else{
            return false
        }
        guard email.contains("@")&&email.contains(".")else{
             return false
        }
        guard password.count>=6 else {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

The eror is at "guard validate()" and it says "Cannot find *validate* in scope"

Comment: Where did you put the `validate()` function?

Comment: It is in a view model file. Or what do you mean by that(sorry, but i am a beginner)

Comment: oh, i forgot to mention. I used firebase as a data base

Comment: `validate()` must return a Bool as your code is written, does it?

Comment: yes, validate() shoudl return a bool

Comment: Should? Well does it?

Comment: Ah, I added the whole code of the register view model. Maybe it helps

Comment: The error in the title doesn’t match the error at the bottom of the text so that was confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your function declaration:

```
    private func valdiate() -> Bool{
```

should be:

```
    private func validate() -> Bool{
```

Comment: Damnn man, I really didn't see that. I feel so noob right now. Thank you very much